# Which one of the following class definitions is a valid definition of a class that cannot be instantiated? (Abstract classes)

Tags: java, abstract-class

I don't understand why the answer isn't B and C instead of only C.

A. Invalid because you need to make the class abstract since there is an abstract function inside.

```
class Ghost
{
    abstract void haunt();
}
```

B. This is not the correct answer, but I don't understand why since it is an abstract class, and they cannot be instantiated. The other option is that it's an invalid definition, but I don't see how it can be invalid, it only has a function call.

```
abstract class Ghost
{
    void haunt();
}
```

C. This is the correct answer

```
abstract class Ghost
{
    void haunt() { };
}
```

D. It's not a class but a method so it can't be instantiated

```
abstract Ghost
{
    abstract void haunt();
}
```

E. Needs 'abstract' instead of 'static'

```
static class Ghost
{
    abstract haunt();
}
```

Comment: B is invalid because it has to declare the method `abstract` since it does not implement it.

Comment: B is just syntax stuff: if the method has no implementation (no braces), then it has to be declared abstract

Comment: Also something important to understand is interfaces vs. abstract classes. When using an interface the method signature in B would be correct because an interface doesn't define any method context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B is invalid because the method **haunt** has no implementation and not declared `abstract`. It should be

```
abstract class Ghost{
   abstract void haunt();
}
```

Only interfaces can declare abstract methods without declaring them abstract explicitly

```
interface Gost{
  void haunt(); 
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, we didn't get to interfaces yet (we will soon), but basically if you have an abstract class with no abstract methods, it will be invalid?

Comment: @drossy11 No, an abstract class doesn't need to have an abstract method, but it allows them

Comment: Oh, is it because there's no curly braces with a definition inside that B is invalid?

Comment: @drossy11 yes, because there is no implementation

Answer (score 0):

In option B

```
void haunt();
```

is not a method call, it's actually a method definition and it's invalid because it doesn't have method body and doesn't marked as abstract.